# Traversing down the DOM Node/Elements is GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I have an inline HTML object (`com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.InlineHTML`) and I would like to recursively traverse the Node Elements to find the “input” node (see below) and gets it type (in the below example – a checkbox) however it seems that everything that I try does not seem to want to work by using Node & Element but keep hitting issues..

Anyone have any suggestions on how I would go about doing this - or better yet, point me to some code?

Thanks,

`

```
    <p class="x-date">2010</p>

    <div class="x-img-atv"></div>
    <div class="x-actions">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" xhref="SS"> <span class="x-sprite delete">delete</span>delete</a></li>
            <input type="checkbox">
            <li><a href="#" xhref=""> <span class="x-sprite email">email</span>email</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" xhref="XSS"> <span class="x-sprite review">review</span>review</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT has an integrated [XML parser](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.xml.client.XMLParser.html). It can be used to transform a valid XML element into it's node Objects where you can navigate yourself to the right position or the right element.

Here is an example how you can use it:

```
package XXXX.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Node;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.NodeList;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.XMLParser;

    public class XMLparser_ implements EntryPoint {

        public void onModuleLoad() {

            //a really simple XML sample
            final String xmlString = "<div><p>helle</p><p>World</p></div>";

            Document xml = XMLParser.parse(xmlString);

            //get the nodelist of the Document element can be more than one
            NodeList nodesRoot = xml.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodesRoot.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodesRoot.item(i);
                RootPanel.get().add(new Label(node.toString()));

                //get the childs of the first node
                NodeList nodesChild = node.getChildNodes();         
                for (int j = 0; j < nodesChild.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node node2 = nodesChild.item(j);
                    RootPanel.get().add(new Label(node2.toString()));
                }
            }

            SafeHtml safeHTML = new SafeHtml() {

                @Override
                public String asString() {
                    return xmlString;
                }
            };

            RootPanel.get().add(new HTML(safeHTML));

        }
    }
```

This is the result:

```
<div><p>helle</p><p>World</p></div>
<p>helle</p>
<p>World</p>
helle

World
```

Comment: Many thanks Stefan - however is there no way of doing this via the DOM/Element/Node classes as that is what I have a handle on (with the HTML elements defined)?

Comment: Not sure if understood that coorectly. Do you have a single element, with the given content, or do you have a DOM sturcture with a reference to this element (so is the content on your page and you somehow just got the InlineHTML elment)?

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that the XMLParser itself wraps the browser's own parsing and Element/Node classes. Getting html attributes can be done from the xml Element.getAttribute(String) method. But if you are working from existing dom Elements, you can traverse them in the same way described above, just create the root element from inserting your fragment into an existing element (Document.createDiv()) with setInnerHtml.